# Unable to add background image to a div using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to simply add a background image but I guess that the path is wrong. I tried changing the paths but none of them worked. Am I missing something?

My HTML:

```html
<div class="w-1/3 flex flex-col p-2 bg-wave rounded-md m-2 mb-2">
    <!--some code here-->
</div>
```

My `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: { 
     backgroundImage:{
      'wave':"url:('..public/waves.png')"
     }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

My structure:

```
public
  output.css
  waves.png
index.html
tailwind.config.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `url:('..public/waves.png')` to `url:('/public/waves.png')`.